# How to make a dynamic port forwarding on python?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, portforwarding, asyncore

I modified the code ([found here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/483730-port-forwarding/)) a bit (added class AsyncEventLoop)

```
import socket,asyncore
import threading

class forwarder(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, ip, port, remoteip,remoteport,backlog=5):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.remoteip=remoteip
        self.remoteport=remoteport
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.set_reuse_addr()
        self.bind((ip,port))
        self.listen(backlog)

    def handle_accept(self):
        conn, addr = self.accept()
        # print '--- Connect --- '
        sender(receiver(conn),self.remoteip,self.remoteport)
    def closef(self):
        self.close()

class receiver(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self,conn):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self,conn)
        self.from_remote_buffer=''
        self.to_remote_buffer=''
        self.sender=None

    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_read(self):
        read = self.recv(4096)
        # print '%04i -->'%len(read)
        self.from_remote_buffer += read

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.to_remote_buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.to_remote_buffer)
        # print '%04i <--'%sent
        self.to_remote_buffer = self.to_remote_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
        if self.sender:
            self.sender.close()

class sender(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, receiver, remoteaddr,remoteport):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.receiver=receiver
        receiver.sender=self
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((remoteaddr, remoteport))

    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_read(self):
        read = self.recv(4096)
        # print '<-- %04i'%len(read)
        self.receiver.to_remote_buffer += read

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.receiver.from_remote_buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.receiver.from_remote_buffer)
        # print '--> %04i'%sent
        self.receiver.from_remote_buffer = self.receiver.from_remote_buffer[sent:]

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()
        self.receiver.close()

class AsyncEventLoop(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        asyncore.loop()
```

starting in the code

```
ser = forwarder('127.0.0.1', 7774, 'google.com.ua', 80)
evLoop = AsyncEventLoop()
```

Can I change `remoteip, remoteport` on the fly? If the fly is not possible to change, as well stop this thread to start with the new settings (remoteip, remoteport)?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can

```
ser.remoteip, ser.remoteport = IP, port
```